# Load file contents into a static array of bytes

Tags: arrays, rust, macros, compile-time-constant

I have a static array initialized with some constant value:

```
static PROG_ROM: [u8; 850] = [0x12, 0x1d, ...];
```

I would like to instead load at compile-time the contents of a file into it. Sounds like a job for [`std::include_bytes!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html), however, I have two problems with it:

1. The type of `include_bytes!("foo.dat")` is `&[u8; 850]` i.e. it is a reference. I need this to be a bonafide static array.
2. Even if there was an `include_bytes_static!` macro with type `[u8;850]`, I would have to use it like this:

   ```
   static PROG_ROM: [u8; 850] = include_bytes_static!("foo.dat");
   ```

   I.e. I would have to hardcode the length of the file. Instead, I
   would like to take the length from the length of the file contents.

So the ideal replacement for my code would be a macro to replace the whole definition, i.e. look something like this:

```
define_included_bytes!(PROG_ROM, "foo.dat")
```

and it would expand to

```
static PROG_ROM: [u8; 850] = [0x12, 0x1d, ...];
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: For the first problem, you can just dereference the array, as is is `Copy`. For the second... well, you can write your own. I see no other solution (but perhaps there's a crate for that).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman the definition of `include_bytes!` is "compiler magic", so it's not obvious how I'd write my own version...

Comment: It is compiler magic, but could still be written as a proc macro (and pretty simple one). The only reason it is not (AFAIK) is that the architecture of how libstd is built prevents it from using proc macros, only compiler builtin macros.

Comment: The third option is writing a `build.rs` that creates a `prog_rom.rs`, which you then include like a regular module.

Comment: Rethinking about that, it is indeed possibly to define `include_bytes!()`, but only on nightly because you can locate the current file path with the experimental [`Span::source_file()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.source_file). On stable, you can use a path relative to the crate root or something else from the environment variables Cargo sets.

Comment: See also https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chayim Friedman pointed out you can easily define that proc macro yourself:

```rust
#[proc_macro]
pub fn define_included_bytes(token_stream: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let [ident, _comma, file] = &token_stream.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()[..] else {
        panic!("expected invocation: `define_included_bytes!(IDENTIFIER, \"file_name\");");
    };
    let file = file.to_string().trim_matches('\"').to_string();
    let data: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read(&file).expect(&format!("File {:?} could not be read", file));
    format!("const {ident}: [u8; {}] = {:?};", data.len(), data).parse().unwrap()
}
```

Obviously this is just a hacked together proof of concept and you should thouroughly check the tokens instead of just assuming they're correct.

Comment: I can see how this could be extended to actually look at the tokens -- but what about dependency tracking?

Answer (score 2):

Use `*include_bytes!(..)` to get a `[u8; _]` instead of `&[u8; _]` (since arrays implement `Copy`), and use `include_bytes!(..).len()` (which is a const method) to specify the length of the array in the type:

```rust
static PROG_ROM: [u8; include_bytes!("foo.dat").len()] = *include_bytes!("foo.dat");
```

Comment: Is there any compile-time performance cost to doing `include_bytes!` twice?

Comment: @Cactus Possibly, but I would assume it's likely less than alternative approaches, such as using proc macros or build scripts, since those would need to be compiled separately first before they could be used, whereas `include_bytes!` is built into the compiler. Though as is often recommended for these kinds of things, if you care about performance you should benchmark different solutions to find out which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [cafce25's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74813392/477476), I ended up writing the following version using [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.105/syn/index.html) and [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0.21/quote/):

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream, Result};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Ident, Token, LitStr};
use quote::quote;

struct StaticInclude {
    name: Ident,
    filepath: String,
}

impl Parse for StaticInclude {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let name: Ident = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![=]>()?;
        let filepath: String = input.parse::<LitStr>()?.value();
        Ok(StaticInclude{ name, filepath })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn progmem_include_bytes(tokens: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let StaticInclude{ name, filepath } = parse_macro_input!(tokens as StaticInclude);

    let data: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read(&filepath).expect(&format!("File {:?} could not be read", filepath));
    let len = data.len();
    TokenStream::from(quote! {
        #[link_section = ".progmem.data"]
        static #name: [u8; #len] = [#(#data),*];
    })
}
```

(never mind the `link_section` attribute, that's an [AVR-ism](https://docs.rs/avr-progmem/0.3.1/avr_progmem/index.html)).

This works well, except Cargo is not tracking the dependency on the external file, so if its content changes, the program using `progmem_include_bytes!` is not recompiled by `cargo build`.